# Fill The grid - 3.0

Tags: pattern, number-sequence, sequence

> Can you fill this grid ? Version ($\pi$)
>   [image]

In text:

```
?14516
243748
120581
17186?
01?857
```

***HINT 1***

> It's a big spiral!!!

***HINT 2***

> It starts from 0 at the center!

***HINT 3***

> Colors included to identify

Comment: Wait, are you declaring π = 3.0 now? [Indiana, is that you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Pi_Bill)?

Comment: 3rd partial sum in some $\pi$ approximation?

Comment: No, 3.0 stands for my 3rd puzzle and $\pi$ is the clue.

Comment: Rubio LOL!( I love this site!)

Comment: @PiIsNot3 ... Rubio's comment...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final grid is

> ```
> 014516
> 243748
> 120581
> 171869
> 010857
> ```

And the pattern is

> A clockwise spiral out from the center of the following function, displayed such that each digit of a multidigit number occupies one grid square
>  f(1)=0, f(n+1)=f(n)+O(n+(-1)^n) where O(n) is the nth odd number, or 2n-1
>  example: f(2) = f(1)+O(3) = 0+5 = 5, F(3) = f(2)+O(2) = 5+3 = 8...

Comment: One member deleted a  comment using more intuitive solution, based on sequence  of "almost squares" $0,5,8,17,24,37,48,65,80,101,120,145,168,197$ which represents $f(n)=n^2-(-1)^n$. Of course your solution is totaly equivalent, so upvoted it.

Comment: I must be missing something obvious here - but how does this link with  being the clue?